# Adding Reciprocals in ACL2

Tags: lisp, acl2

I am very new to ACL2 so I understand that some of you may feel this is such a simple solution that you would frown upon my outreach for help. I am trying to figure out how to get my code to add up to an Nth reciprocal squared (I.E if n=4 then i am looking for 1/1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16)

I have a function that will add up to n and it works and looks like this

```
(defun sum-up-to-n (n)
(if (zp n)
       0
       (+ n (sum-up-to-n (- n 1)))))
```

With the the Reciprocal squared looking like this

```
(defun sum-up-to-nSqRecip (n)
   (if (zp n)
       0
         (+  (sum-up-to-nSqRecip (- n 1))) 1/n^2) ))
```

I receive this error "The body of 
SUM-UP-TO-NSQRECIP contains a free occurrence of the variable symbol
|1/N^2|.  Note that |1/N^2| occurs in the context of condition (NOT (ZP N))
from a surrounding IF test." and i do not know how to resolve this error.

included stuff

```
(encapsulate nil
  (set-state-ok t)
  (program)
  (defun check-expect-fn (left right sexpr state)
    (if (equal left right)
      (mv nil (cw "check-expect succeeded: ~x0~%" sexpr) state)
      (er soft nil "check-expect failed: ~x0
      Expected: ~x1
      Actual:   ~x2" sexpr right left)))
  (defmacro check-expect (&whole sexpr left right)
    `(check-expect-fn ,left ,right (quote ,sexpr) state))
  (logic))

(include-book "doublecheck" :uncertified-okp t :dir :teachpacks)
(include-book "arithmetic-5/top" :uncertified-okp t :dir :system)
```

Comment: How is it that you know that subtraction should be written as `(- ...)` but you don't know that division is written as `(/ ...)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ACL2 uses LISP syntax, which means you need prefix operators. So 1/n^2 should be (/ 1 (* n n)).

LISP allows a lot of the characters to be in a name, 1/n^2 in your example is treated as a name of a variable, which isn't binded to anything (not an input either). This is why you are receiving the "free occurrence of the variable" error.

Comment: I knew that. I did that. And yet c++ just took over. Thank you so much!!!